# Can't compact local NPM couchdb registry

Tags: couchdb, npm

I've been trying to compact a rather large NPM registry I have replicated on a local server.  Right now the db is 198gb (first half of question, is this way to large? or appropriate for the npm registry?)

I have been trying to use the couchdb compact directions I found here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Compaction  They seem pretty simple, but I keep getting an error `{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}` when I attempt to compact.

Any suggestions?  Is it just set up wrong?  The registry and database work fine, I'm just out of disk space once again.

Here is what I am trying and what I get for responses on the compact commands:

```
curl -H GET http://registry.mysite.com:5984/
{"db_name":"registry","doc_count":19634,"doc_del_count":1735,"update_seq":62801,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":211813023744,"instance_start_time":"1356715631498583","disk_format_version":5,"committed_update_seq":62801}


curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://registry.mysite.com:5984/registry/_compact
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

Its this second post, the one with the _compact that should return a 202.

If I do a GET on the "registry" I get a valid response.

```
curl -H GET http://registry.mysite.com:5984/registry
{"_id":"registry","_rev":"33-55c69be715a3b60e4968c809487493ec","name":"registry","description":"Experimental namespace...
```

On the server I get the following error on _compact call:

```
[Fri, 28 Dec 2012 18:13:32 GMT] [info] [<0.29288.0>] 192.168.13.54 - - 'POST' /registry/_design/app/_rewrite/registry/_compact 404
```

Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had a rewrite rule messing everything up.

```
registry.mysite.com = /registry/_design/app/_rewrite
```

Now the log reflects the right URL and looks like compact should work